# Why is std::is_same false for subclasses?

Tags: c++, std, type-traits

Why isn't subclass B the same as base class A?

I know B is A but A isn't B, but if is_same doesn't return true for these cases then I feel its use is limited.

Is there a std function that could return true in this case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because [`is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) checks for the **same** type, and `B` is not the same type as `A`. What you want is [`is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of). Also these are metafunctions, not functions, and are more commonly referred to as type traits.

We can verify this with a simple program:

```
struct A {};     
struct B : A {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
      << std::is_same<A, A>::value << ' '        // true
      << std::is_same<A, const A>::value << ' '  // false!
      << std::is_same<A, B>::value << ' '        // false
      << std::is_base_of<A, B>::value << ' '     // true
      << std::is_base_of<B, A>::value << ' '     // false
      << std::is_base_of<A, A>::value << ' '     // true!
      << std::endl;
}
```

As TC points out in the comments, `is_base_of` also considers inaccessible/ambiguous bases, so perhaps you might also want to consider [`is_convertible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible), which does not. Example:

```
struct B { };
struct D : private B { };

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << std::is_base_of<B, D>::value << ' '   // true
        << std::is_convertible<D*, B*>::value    // false, because private
                                                 //   inheritance
        << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `is_convertible` on `A*` and `B*` may or may not be a better choice, depending on the question you want to ask, since `is_base_of` considers inaccessible and ambiguous bases too.